# What to return when printing out Objects using the toString method and a for each loop?

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, tostring, object-to-string

I currently have a toString method, similar to the one below. Please ignore that the Objects are only temporarily named. I have done this so that there is no confusion between the types of each variable etc.:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    for(Object object : ArrayList) {
        System.out.println("This object is a " + object.getVariableA() + " and a " + object.getVariableB() + ".");
    }
    return null;
}
```

However the toString method requires me to return a value. I would obviously just want to return the Strings that I'm printing, although if I place a return statement there, it will only print one Object and not all of the ones I am looping through. What would be the best way to print all these values and not simply return null as I don't want this printing out after all the Objects? I also want to ensure that each of these Objects are printed on separate lines like they currently are so please don't suggest solutions that include one long joined String without line breaks as this is not suitable in this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: toString() is supposed to return a string containing a "description" of the object. It's not supposed to print anything. Read the javadoc of Object.toString().

Comment: @JBNizet That was my initial comment but then realized the OP was just demonstrating what they'd *like* to return. That said ... "so please don't suggest solutions that include one long joined String " ... well, then yes, **You're doing it wrong**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`toString` shouldn't output anything **at all**. Its job is to return an appropriate string representation of the relevant object, not to *output* that representation anywhere. That's outside its problem domain.

Instead, build and return a string (probably by using a `StringBuilder`).

E.g., something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(some_appropriate_size);
    for(Object object : ArrayList) {
        sb.append("This object is a ")
          .append(object.getVariableA())
          .append(" and a ")
          .append(object.getVariableB())
          .append(".\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

> I also want to ensure that each of these Objects are printed on separate lines like they currently are so please don't suggest solutions that include one long joined String as this is not suitable in this situation.

The above puts the items from the array list on separate "lines" (via the `\n`). But "one long joined String" is the **only** appropriate thing for `toString` to do. If you want a different result, you must use a different method, rather than breaking the contract of `toString`.

Comment: +1 You're doing a String concatenation inside the append. :) It would be more efficient to chain calls to append.

Comment: @ZouZou: True enough.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, this is a great solution. Although currently the StringBuilder adds a new line on the last printed String and this is not wanted. How do I go about ensuring the last String does not end with a new line, "\n"?

Comment: @edwoollard: There are lots of ways. You could add `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length())` just after the loop, for instance. Or use `"."` in the last append and have a variable that you use for the *first* append, which initially contains `"The object is a "` but then gets set, on the first loop (after the append), to `"\nThe object is a "`. Or have a flag, `boolean first = true`; and have `if (first) { first = false; } else { sb.append("\n"); }` at the beginning of the loop. Or...

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `String` and add what you want each iteration:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    for(Object object : ArrayList) {
        result += "This object is a " + object.getVariableA() + " and a " + object.getVariableB() + ".\n");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Don't forget to add the `"\n"` new-line character, so you print each "partial result" in one different line.

Comment: s/String/StringBuilder/

Answer (score -1):

You state in your question that:

> I also want to ensure that each of these Objects are printed on separate lines like they currently are so please don't suggest solutions that include one long joined String as this is not suitable in this situation.

Then you probably shouldn't be using `toString()`; that's not what's it's for. It is for returning a single string that is some representation of the object. It should *never* be outputting anything.

Add a getter to your class that returns the `List` of objects, output them as you would like. If you really wanted to make the class self-printing, add a `print(OutputStream os)` method that takes the supplied `OutputStream` (or maybe a `PrintStream` instead) and will do so.

Comment: I edited my question to re-word it. I did want to return a String but I wanted to ensure people grasped that I wanted it to be returned with multiple lines. I thought I might find solutions with one ridiculously lengthy String as there is a lot of content to be displayed and therefore not practical in my example.

Comment: Even so, it really doesn't sound like you're using `toString()` as intended. It's really not meant for that.

Comment: I'm completely content using a `StringBuilder` and returning that from the `toString()` method, so yes, I am using it how it's intended. This is why I asked the question on StackOverflow in the first place.